# Running a simple Hibernate project has no effect

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.2, hibernate 4.3.0 final.

I have `testClass`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="testClass")

public class testClass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Created from another class's method:

```
try {
   new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
   new testClass();
} catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

Here is my hibernate.xml.cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="postgres">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="testClass"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

It executes on jboss server side:

```
[2014-01-06 05:59:01,592] Artifact server:ejb: Artifact is deployed successfully
17:59:22,880 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
17:59:22,881 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
17:59:22,889 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Configured SessionFactory: postgres
```

But nothing happens :( 
I'm checking for new tables in my PostgresDB but there's nothing.

What did I miss?

Comment: I think you are doing nothing; just open it and read it

Comment: Thanks for a great question with all the right details, right from the start. I'd +10 if I could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What did you expect to happen?

You create a new empty entity, then you exit.

You don't `persist()` the entity with an entity manager (or in Hibernate terms, `save()` to a `Session`). So it never exists as far as the database is concerned. It is just a plain Java object like any other, and gets garbage collected when the last reference to it is removed.

You need to:

- Use the `Configuation` to produce a `SessionFactory` and store the `SessionFactory` somewhere accessible. You don't want to create this all the time, it should be created on startup. Container-managed persistence and injection can be handy here.
- Obtain a `Session` from the `SessionFactory`
- Pass the new object to `Session.save(...)`, so it gets `INSERT`ed in the DB after proper key generation, etc.

It might be a good idea to re-read a Hibernate and/or JPA tutorial to cover the basics of the object life cycle. [The Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/quickstart/en-US/html/) may be a good starting point, particularly [the section on native Hibernate APIs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/quickstart/en-US/html/ch02.html).

Personally, if I was doing basic stuff I'd use the JPA APIs instead, though. `PersistenceUnit`, `EntityManager`, etc. See [Getting started with Hibernate and JPA](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/quickstart/en-US/html/ch04.html).